# An extremal coloring problem

Tags: graph-theory

Is it true that there  is $c\in\big[\frac{n}2,n+1\big]\cap\Bbb Z$ such that following holds if you assign single color to each edge of complete graph $K_n$:

If $c$ colors are used in total, then every coloring contains a simple $4$-cycle with each color assigned to the cycle colors even number of edges.

If $c+1$ colors are used in total, then there is a coloring such that every simple $4$-cycle has odd number of edges assigned to each color.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding. There are $n(n-1)/2$ edges. Each color has to be used a positive number of times.

Comment: what is a simple cycle?

Comment: @dREaM only start, end vertices are same.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question, it could probably be more clearly and concisely worded as: Let $c(n)$ be the minimum number of colors with which the edges of $G = K_n$ can be colored so that each 4-cycle has at least 3 colors, or has exactly 2 colors with 2 edges of each color, then you want to know whether $\frac{n}{2}+1 \leq c(n) \leq n+2$. Is there any reason you're interested in this particular problem? It seems very specific. Many similar problems have been studied before (see http://www.math.kit.edu/iag6/~axenovich/media/zoltan_dhruv_ram_bip.pdf , for example).

Comment: This will give me lower bound and upper bound on distinct colors needed on edges. I have an $n^2$ upper bound.

Comment: @PerryElliott-Iverson Is answer for this question known?

Comment: @Turbo It's such a specific problem, especially the bit about requiring exactly 2 edges of each color, that I imagine it's not in the literature. You might be able to get decent bounds based on other results in the literature, but I haven't thought about it enough to tell you for certain.